# Display specified data from MySQL using button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

[image]

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>   
  <th>id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Phone_number</th>
  <th>Type</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button">Display normal user</button> 
<button type="button">Display premium user</button>
```

I had created a table for display the data from mysql database. How to let the button when clicked will only display the specify data like the "Display normal user" will only display the user_type which was normal user

Comment: Make a form, submit it, get the submitted option in PHP, run a query, output the results. The basics of every web application in the world. Have you studied any HTML forms / PHP tutorials?

Comment: There are two different ways of going about this; doing DOM changes on client side using JS only (basically show/hide table rows) or performing an AJAX call to fetch filtered data. Up to you to pick one that best suits your needs and try to implement it. That's assuming you're looking for a Javascript solution.

Comment: I guess you are looking for this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Your screenshot looks like PHP My Admin? Do you actually have a table that you created? If so, post the HTML markup/css and the JS code...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh the grid based on the current selection, you will need to implement a filter system.

You will have to determine what you are filtering by and send a query to the server to execute some SQL similar to following:

```sql
select * from `user` where `user_type` = 'Normal User'; -- or 'Premium User'
```

After you receive all users or filtered users (if filtering is active), you can redraw the table.

```js
const userTable = document.querySelector('.user-table');
const tbody = userTable.querySelector('tbody');
  
const normalFilter = document.querySelector('button[data-filter-value="Normal User"]');
const premiumFilter = document.querySelector('button[data-filter-value="Premium User"]');

const main = () => { 
  normalFilter.addEventListener('click', toggleButtonActiveState);
  premiumFilter.addEventListener('click', toggleButtonActiveState);
  
  addRows(tbody, selectAll());
};

const sqlData = `
id,username,phone_number,user_type
1,Ali,0123456789,Normal User
2,James,1123456789,Premium User
3,Will,2123456789,Normal User
4,Mary,3123456789,Premium User
5,Time,4123456789,Normal User
`.trim();

const toggleFilter = btn => btn.dataset.filterActive = !strToBool(btn.dataset.filterActive);
const strToBool = str => str === 'false' ? false : !!str;
const xor = (a, b) => (a || b) && !(a && b);

const toggleButtonActiveState = e => {
  toggleFilter(e.target);
  refreshTable();
};

const selectAll = () => (
  ([ head, ...tail ]) =>
    (fields =>
      tail.map(line =>
        line.split(',').reduce((acc, value, index) =>
    ({ ...acc, [fields[index]]: value }), {})))
  (head.split(',')))
(sqlData.split('\n'));

const findByUserType = (type) =>
  selectAll().filter(({ user_type }) => user_type === type);

const addRows = (tbody, records) => {
  records.forEach(record => {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    Object.values(record).forEach(value => {
      const td = document.createElement('td');
      td.textContent = value;
      tr.append(td);
    });
    tbody.append(tr);
  });
};

const currentFilter = () => Object
  .fromEntries([...document.querySelectorAll('button[data-type="filter"]')]
    .map(filter => [
      filter.dataset.filterValue,
      strToBool(filter.dataset.filterActive)
    ]));

const query = (filter) =>
  !xor(filter['Normal User'], filter['Premium User'])
    ? selectAll()
    : filter['Premium User']
      ? findByUserType('Premium User')
      : findByUserType('Normal User');

const refreshTable = () => {
  tbody.innerHTML = '';
  addRows(tbody, query(currentFilter()));
};

main();
```

```css
.user-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 100%;
}

.user-table,
.user-table th,
.user-table td {
  
}

.user-table th,
.user-table td {
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.user-table thead th {
  text-align: left;
  color: #235A81;
}

.user-table thead tr {
  background: #DFDFDF;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #DFDFDF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
}

.user-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #DFDFDF;
}

button[data-type="filter"] {
  background: #EEE;
  border: thin solid grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

button[data-type="filter"]:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

button[data-filter-active="true"],
button[data-filter-active="true"]:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-type="filter"
    data-filter-active="false" data-filter-field="user_type"
    data-filter-value="Normal User">
  Display "Normal User"</button> 
<button type="button" data-type="filter"
    data-filter-active="false" data-filter-field="user_type"
    data-filter-value="Premium User">
  Display "Premium User"</button>
<hr />  
<table class="user-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>username</th>
      <th>phone_number</th>
      <th>user_type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```